# Is there a contradiction in these two definitions of limit Superior?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

**Definition 1 :** Let $A=\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers not necessarily bounded . Then we define :

$\lim \sup ~ a_n = \inf ~\{\sup ~a_n,~\sup ~a_{n+1}~\sup ~a_{n+2}, \cdots\} $

**Definition 2 :** If $A =\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers which is bounded above, then the limit superior of $A$ denoted by $S$ is the infimum of those real numbers $v$ with the property that there are only a finite number of natural numbers $n$ such that $v < a_n$

Please consider this image : [image]

Let the sequence $A$ denoted on the number line  be bounded above by $b$ and may or may not be bounded below. ( In this case, we have taken $A$ to be bounded below by $a$ as well)

Now, $\{\sup ~a_n,~\sup ~a_{n+1}~\sup ~a_{n+2}, \cdots\}$ is a monotonically decreasing and bounded sequence which converges to the point $S . S_o =~ \sup ~a_n , S_1 = ~\sup ~a_{n+1}$ and so on.

**Question 1:** As per definition $2$, there can only be a finite numbers of terms to the right of $S$. But how can this be possible here when we have a whole sequence of supremums itself convering towards $S$.

**Question 2:** What could happen when $A$ is not bounded below? I fail to understand how can only a finite number of terms be there on the right side of $S$.

Thank you for help.

Comment: The infimum of a set need not belong to the set. For every $T > S$, there are only finitely many $n$ such that $a_n > T$.

Comment: that means, $S$ need not belong to $A$ .. but still, there can be infinite elements greater than $T$ ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\sup a_n$?

Comment: The way you have written it, definition 1 does not make sense. The notation $\sup\{a_n, a_{n+1},\dots\}$ means supremum of all terms of the sequence starting with $a_n$. If you want to write $\{\sup a_n,\sup a_{n+1},\dots\}$, then $a_n$ has to be a set, not a number.

Comment: Another problem with your definition 1 is that you need to take infimum from a set of numbers. You probably wanted to write something like $\inf_{n\in\mathbb N} \sup\{a_k; k\ge n\}$, which is another way of writing $\inf \{\sup\{a_k; k\ge n\}; n\in\mathbb N\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that this makes things clear for you.

Let $A$ denote a sequence $\left(a_{n}\right)$.

Definition 1a) $\limsup A:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_{n}$ where
$s_{n}:=\sup\left\{ a_{k}\mid k\geq n\right\} $

The fact that sequence $\left(s_{n}\right)$ is non-increasing makes
it possible to define equivalently:

Definition 1b) $\limsup A:=\inf\left\{ s_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} $.

Now define $V:=\left\{ v\in\mathbb{R}\mid\text{the set }\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}\mid v<a_{n}\right\} \text{ is finite}\right\} $
and note:

$$v\in V\iff\exists n\; s_{n}\leq v$$

This shows that $V=\cup_{n=1}\left[s_{n},\infty\right)$ and consequently
$\inf V=\inf\left\{ s_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} =\limsup A$

---

In special case where $A$ is not bounded above we have $s_n=+\infty$ for each $n$ so that $\limsup A=+\infty$. Secondly we have $V=\emptyset$ and $\inf\emptyset:=+\infty$. So everything remains valid in that case.